# Изменение файла js/html посредством JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью JS или каких-либо фреймворков изменять значение переменной непосредственно в файле (с перезаписью этого файла)?
Если да, то что лучше использовать для этой цели.
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: node.js, модуль fs, пакеты парсеров типа jsdom.

Comment: Не совсем понятно.. Какого файла?
JS выполняется на стороне браузера и не имеет доступа к ФС сервера. Для правки файлов, в любом случае должно выполняться что-то на серверной стороне, например php или nodejs. А с браузера только отправляться запрос с аргументом, что нужно поменять тому самому скрипту который работает на стороне сервера.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пока ничего не понятно - погуглю)

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать десктопное приложение через nwjs и необходимо, чтоб значения переменных с предыдущей сессии сохранялись.

Comment: для этого есть [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage). Но я не понял про десктопное приложение... имелось в виду, открываемое в браузере на ПК?

Comment: Nwjs использует Chrome + node и превращает Web проект в десктоп приложение